# Best practice to handle extjs refresh page

Tags: extjs

I wrote an ExtJS application like this:

[image]

the sub menu is dynamic added by clicking the button on the left.

The question is :
as the sub panel is created dynamically, so if I refresh the whole page, the panel will go away. 
What I expected is it could still display the same content before refresh pages.
So, my question is how to  handle this in ExtJS?
Do I need to record the current panel information into Ext.App?

Comment: Don't refresh the whole page, just add the new panel.

Comment: _if I refresh the whole page_, does that mean "If I click browser refresh button"?

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS is a framework to build Web Applications that run inside the browser.

With Web Applications, just like normal applications, you don't close the program and start it anew (like a browser refresh does) just because someone wants to switch to a different toolbar or look at different data. You work with multiple panels, switch between them, and/or open windows.

You could for instance generate multiple panels inside a container with `card` layout, and bring to front the panel that you want to show right now.

If you have a license that allows you to use Sencha Architect, there is a nice "navigation" sample available in Architect from where you can start and look at how it's done.